# Where is the log file in ROS 2.0

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install ROS 2.0 in my computer, and run the demo programs. But I can not find the log file.
Where is the log file in ROS 2.0?

I know the default position in ROS 1.0 is ~/.ros.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283942/where-is-the-log-file-in-ros-2.0/) by [Dragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30020/dragon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The logging subsystem in ROS 2 does not createa a logfile at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30020/dragon/) on 2018-02-28**:
Thanks for your answer. Now if I want to log into a file, how should I do? I can not find any introduction for this.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-03-02**:
For now (until that feature is being implemented) you can use "standard" features available on your system. E.g. pipe the output into a file.

**Comment by [Dragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30020/dragon/) on 2018-03-08**:
en. en. I find the function through source code. Now, it can't log in the file through the ros2.